# What sorting algorithm is this, and how does it work? (If there isn't a name or well-known resource for it.)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, wolfram-mathematica, binary-heap

It's been nearly ten years since I took my DSA class. I've looked through [Wikipedia's list of sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) but none stand out as being this one. It's part of a priority queue implementation, and it appears part of the sorting happens in the push function (`EnQueue`) while the other in the pop function (`DeQueue`).

Here's the original *Mathematica* code, but since most aren't familiar with *Mathematica*, I've translated a little bit, below each function.

```
EnQueue[q : queue[ar_, n_, pred_], val_] := Module[{i, j},
  If[n == Length[ar], ar = Join[ar, makeArray@Length@ar]];
  n++; ar[[n]] = val;
  i = n;
  While[True,
   j = Quotient[i, 2];
   If[j < 1 || pred[ar[[j]], ar[[i]]],
    Break[]
    ];
   ar[[{i, j}]] = {ar[[j]], ar[[i]]};
   i = j;
   ];
  q
  ]
```

The `EnQueue` function first checks if the number of elements `n` has reached the size of the heap `ar`, and if so, doubles the heap. Next, it increments the number of elements and stores the new element at that index (*Mathematica* indices are 1-based, not 0-based). Then, it sets `i` to that index (of the new element), and enters a loop that sets `j` to `floor(i/2)`, *i.e.* some element in the middle of the heap. Now, if `j < 1` (which is equivalent to checking if `i == 1`, as far as I can tell), or if `ar[j]` (the element in the middle) *should* be ahead of `ar[i]` (the new element), then we break. Otherwise, we swap the elements at `i` and `j`, and continue; so in the second iteration, we start with `i` pointing to the *middle*, and `j` pointing to quarter-way.

```
DeQueue[queue[ar_, n_, pred_]] := 
 Module[{i, j, res = ar[[1]]},
  ar[[1]] = ar[[n]]; ar[[n]] = Null; n--;
  j = 1;
  While[j <= Quotient[n, 2],
   i = 2 j;
   If[i < n && pred[ar[[i + 1]], ar[[i]]],
    i++
    ];
   If[pred[ar[[i]], ar[[j]]],
    ar[[{i, j}]] = {ar[[j]], ar[[i]]};
    ];
   j = i];
  res]
```

Meanwhile, `DeQueue` returns the front of the heap, and moves the *back* of the heap to the front (and unsets the back, and decrements the number of elements). Then, starting with `j` pointing to the front, it enters a loop that starts by setting `i` to double `j`. **If `i` is within bounds (pointing to an element) but is out of order with respect to the next element, `i` is incremented. If `i` is in order with respect to `j` (the front; in other words, if the front is *out* of order with respect to `i`), then the two positions are swapped, and `j` is set to the position `i` was at. We continue the loop until `j` passes the middle.**

It's mostly the bolded part above I don't understand. I *think* what it's doing is sorting *half* the heap on `DeQueue`, and doing some part of the sort for a new element in `EnQueue`, but I'm not sure...

Comment: It's usually called heapsort. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). The ordering property to be maintained is that each nth element is greater-equal (or less-equal, depending on the ordering used) to its children, located at positions `2n` and `2n+1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enqueue seems like a min-heap routine to me
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Min_and_Max_Heaps

Dequeue removes the top item of a heap, which is stored in the first item of an array, then replaces it with the last item of the array and sifts it down the heap, swapping it each time with a child as long as a child is smaller than the item (and smaller than its sibling, if it has one). That stops when there's no smaller child, i.e. when the item reaches the heap bottom or it is smaller than its children (or child, it there's only one).

**EDIT:** Words 'enqueue' & 'dequeue' suggest it's a queue. The algorithm is a binary heap implemented in an array, so this is a **priority queue**.

Comment: Ah, searching "Binary Heap" brought up some [pictorial examples](http://interactivepython.org/LpOMZ/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/heap.html) that made it very clear. Indeed it _seemed_ like it was sorting only "half" the array, because the array is actually a representation of a complete tree, and the halved / doubled index operations are actually swapping elements between parent and child nodes.